# Police Misconduct dataset?

Tags: data-request, crime, federal, police

Anyone know where I can find a good dataset on police misconducts? I'd like something similar to what RAND current has out on its policemisconduct.org site, but it looks like its pretty much a Twitter bot scraper.  IE I'm pretty sure the same event is tracked at odd times throughout its disposition.

Related datasets I'm interested in would observe expenditures by police by jurisdiction/agency etc.  I have seen the recent Federal Report on equipment purchases with federal grant monies; it is broken out by type of equipment and from which granting process.  Is this info available somewhere besides PDF form (or how best to parse a PDF with, say, R or Python)?

Lastly, the ex-post observations of the payouts made by cities to citizens who have won misconduct suits against officers would also be of some use, certainly as a measure of "success" in the right contexts.

Comment: Regarding getting data from a PDF, see http://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/4489/scraping-columns-from-a-pdf

Comment: theres a local police force near me that published their internal affairs data annually for a few years. i never really looked at it, but if you're interested i'll find it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, from [PoliceMisconduct.net's own FAQ](http://www.policemisconduct.net/about/npmsrp-faq/):

> **Why do this?**
>
> Simply because nobody else does. Only a small fraction of the 17,000 law enforcement agencies actually track their own misconduct in a semi-public manner, and even when they do, the data they provide is generic and does not specify what misconduct occurred, who did it, and what the end result was.

[This FiveThirtyEight.com article by Reuben Fischer-Baum](http://fivethirtyeight.com/datalab/allegations-of-police-misconduct-rarely-result-in-charges/) goes into more detail about the scarcity of this data:

> As is the case with police shooting statistics, comprehensive numbers on accusations of police misconduct are hard to come by. There is no national reporting requirement for such accusations; in fact, many places have laws to purposefully keep the details of misconduct investigations out of the public eye.

For the article, Fischer-Baum settles for the NPMRP/PoliceMisconduct.net data.

Comment: Thanks.  What do you think might be the best way to "de-dupe" that dataset if it really is picking up each "status update" of each misconduct? It looks like *any* time a misconduct hits Twitter, their bot scrapes it and row binds - but that process doesn't seem like its uniquely identifying the events...

Answer (score 1):

http://www.fatalencounters.org/ Not specifically about misconduct, but attempts to be a database of all fatal encounters will U.S. law enforcement.

Comment: I have been here, and spoken with the admin about his great site. (One wonders what great "good" Periscopic's new .io site would do with the data he's got.) I think (perhaps as the AG gets his act together on a data-driven solution to police and oversight) recent outrage will propel us Data geeks to spend a little of our opportunity costs on aggregating our little piles into some insight.  I hear some calling this notion "Big Data" these days :D

Answer (score 0):

USA Today published a data-story about police misconduct ([archived copy](https://outline.com/FdzvqY))

> Starting with lists of officers who lost their law enforcement certification in 44 states, we are making those records available here.

CSV data: https://gofile.io/?c=bEbPGv

Data snippet (from 30k+ records)

```
"Name:","State:","Agency:","Year decertified:",""
"Gilberto Abad","Georgia","Atlanta Police","2004","https://www.usatoday.com/documents/5977556-Georgia-Decertifications/"
"Daniel G Abair","Georgia","Lee County Sheriff","2012","https://www.usatoday.com/documents/5977556-Georgia-Decertifications/"
```

And each record contains a URL to the pdf/txt documents:

https://assets.documentcloud.org/documents/5977583/New-York-Decertifications.pdf

https://assets.documentcloud.org/documents/5977583/New-York-Decertifications.txt

URL of documents are derived from the URL in the CSV above

---

*([my source](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=19770708))*